# scrlttr2: How to remove the words "Telefon", "E-Mail" & "Url:" sender's address

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

In `scrlttr2` you can include your telephone number, your e-mail and an url into the sender´s address which is good.

However, the document will write "Telefon:", "E-Mail:" and "Url:" (German) in front of the number etc. - even though everyone can see that it is the phone number etc.

Therefore, I would like to delete the words. Is anyone able to do so?

MWE

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,roman,fromlogo=true]{scrlttr2} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %dt. Silbentrennung
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{tgpagella}% Latin Modern typeface (font)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% T1 font encoding for high quality font output

\usepackage{graphicx}

\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,
            fromalign=right,
            fromlogo=true,
            fromphone=true,
            fromurl=true,
            fromemail=true,
            fromrule=afteraddress,
            backaddress=true,
            parskip=half,
            enlargefirstpage=true,
            } 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\enclname}{Anlagen}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Kiwi Diwi}        
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Ender Str. 29\\
                        40987 Köln} 
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0177 66666666}
\setkomavar{fromurl}{www.iglu-lecker.de}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{\href{mailto:meine-email@wikibooks.org}{\texttt{meine-email@wikibooks.org}}}

\setkomavar{subject}{Bewerbung als ...}

\setkomavar{place}{Köln}    

 \setlength{\footskip}{-6pt}        

\begin{document}
 % die Anschrift des Empfaengers
\begin{letter}{Gruppe Chic Schank GmbH\\Personalabteilung\\Harald Peters\\ Alte Straße 28\\85922 Köln}      

\date{\today}
\opening{}
\makelettertitle

text text

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Philip, you simply need to add an *[]* inside the `\setkomavar{fromphone}{0177 66666666}` command: `\setkomavar{fromphone}[]{0177 66666666}`.

Comment: Why are you answering your own question as if you would be a different person?

Comment: I found it funny.

Comment: at least, it's the best answer..

Answer (score 4):

On page 139 of the documentation of KOMA-Script (`texdoc koma-script`) you can read the following:

> ```
> \setkomavar{name}[description]{content}
> \setkomavar*{name}{description}
> ```
>
> With the command `\setkomavar` you determine the `content` of the
>   variable `name`. Using an optional argument you can at the same time
>   change the `description` of the variable.
>
> In contrast, `\setkomavar*` can only set the `description` of the
>   variable `name`.

To complete this, command `\setkomavar{name}[description]{content}` prints `description: content` in your letter, asuming that the separator is `:`. 
So you have two possibilities to get what you want:

```
\setkomavar{fromphone}[]{0177 66666666}
%\setkomavar{fromphone}[]{telephone number}
\setkomavar{fromurl}[]{www.iglu-lecker.de}
\setkomavar{fromemail}[]{\href{mailto:meine-email@wikibooks.org}{\texttt{meine-email@wikibooks.org}}}
```

deletes in all three cases the printing of `description`.  Or you can use

```
\setkomavar*{fromphone}{}
\setkomavar*{fromurl}{}
\setkomavar*{fromemail}{}
```

to delete the predefined `description`.

Another posibility could be to use symbols (option `symbolicnames=true` of KOMA-Script) instead of the descriptions ...

Compplete mwe with first possibility:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,roman,fromlogo=true]{scrlttr2} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %dt. Silbentrennung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{tgpagella}% Latin Modern typeface (font)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% T1 font encoding for high quality font output

\usepackage{graphicx}

\KOMAoptions{%
  paper=a4,
  fromalign=right,
  fromlogo=true,
  fromphone=true,
  fromurl=true,
  fromemail=true,
  fromrule=afteraddress,
  backaddress=true,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=true,
} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\enclname}{Anlagen}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Kiwi Diwi}        
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Ender Str. 29\\
                        40987 Köln} 
\setkomavar{fromphone}[]{0177 66666666} % <=============================
%\setkomavar{fromphone}[]{telephone number}
\setkomavar{fromurl}[]{www.iglu-lecker.de} % <==========================
\setkomavar{fromemail}[]{\href{mailto:meine-email@wikibooks.org}{\texttt{meine-email@wikibooks.org}}}

\setkomavar{subject}{Bewerbung als ...}

\setkomavar{place}{Köln}    

\setlength{\footskip}{-6pt}        

\begin{document}
 % die Anschrift des Empfaengers
\begin{letter}{Gruppe Chic Schank GmbH\\Personalabteilung\\Harald Peters\\ Alte Straße 28\\85922 Köln}      

\date{\today}
\opening{Dear ??????,} % <==============================================
%\makelettertitle % <===================================================

text text

%\makeletterclosing
\closing{Greetings} % <=================================================

\end{letter} % <========================================================
\end{document}
```

Please see the several code corrections marked in my MWE with `<============`.

The code gives the resulting pdf:

[image: added image of pdf]